# Login user and navigation back to home page Shell

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Shell in my Xamarin forms application,
I have an issue when My user registers successfully he is redirected to Homepage, however there is no Tab Menu on the bottom while if I redirect him to AppShell the page is blank. Do you have any suggestions?

My redirection

```
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AppShell());
```

My AppShell

```
<TabBar >
        <Tab  x:Name="HomePage" Icon="home.png" Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LabelHome}" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab  x:Name="Categories" Icon="collections.png " Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LabelCategory}">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CategoriesPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab  x:Name="Add" Icon="add.png" Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LabelAddingPage}">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AddingPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab  x:Name="Inbox" Icon="mail.png" Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LabelInbox}" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:InboxPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab  x:Name="Profile" Icon="userg.png" Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LabelProfil}">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:UserProfilePage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

And my app

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from  your redirection `await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AppShell());` , i think you have another Shell Application just for your login.

try `await App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();` to initialize the Shell as your mainPage.

hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make the following changes :-

1. Your redirection should be :-

   ```
       await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//main");
   ```
2. Your App Shell should have this :-

   ```
   <TabBar Route="main">
   ...   
   </TabBar>
   ```

Hopefully this helps.